# What is synonym propagation?

Tags: static-analysis

I am currently reading *SmartCheck: Static Analysis of Ethereum Smart Contracts* (Tikhomirov et al., WETSEB'18; [PDF](http://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/35862/1/smartcheck-paper.pdf)). In section 3.1 it talks briefly about synonym propagation.

What is synonym propagation?

I searched in the Dragon Book, but I did not manage to find it.